# An error in my code to be a simple ftp

Tags: sockets, python-2.6

I met an error when running codes at the bottom. It's like a simple ftp.
I use python2.6.6 and CentOS release 6.8
In most linux server, it gets right results like this:(I'm very sorry that I have just sign up and couldn't )
Clinet:

```
[root@Test ftp]# python client.py 
path:put|/home/aaa.txt
```

Server:

```
[root@Test ftp]# python server.py 
connected...
pre_data:put|aaa.txt|4
cmd: put
file_name: aaa.txt
file_size: 4
upload successed.
```

But I get errors in some server(such as my own VM in my PC). I have done lots of tests(python2.6/python2.7, Centos6.5/Centos6.7) and found this error is not because them. Here is the error imformation:

```
[root@Lewis-VM ftp]# python server.py 
connected...
pre_data:put|aaa.txt|7sdfsdf           ###Here gets the wrong result, "sdfsdf" is the content of /home/aaa.txt  and it shouldn't be sent here to  'file_size' and so it  cause the "ValueError" below

cmd: put
file_name: aaa.txt
file_size: 7sdfsdf

----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 10699)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 570, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 332, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 627, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "server.py", line 30, in handle
    if int(file_size)>recv_size:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '7sdfsdf\n'
```

What's more, I found that if I insert a time.sleep(1) between `sk.send(cmd+"|"+file_name+'|'+str(file_size))` and `sk.send(data)` in client.py, the error will disappear. I have said that I did tests in different system and python versions and the error is not because them. So I guess that is it because of some system configs?  I have check about socket.send() and socket.recv() in python.org but fount nothing helpful. So could somebody help me to explain why this happend?

The code are here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding:utf-8

################
#This is server#
################

import SocketServer
import os

class MyServer(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        base_path = '/home/ftp/file'
        conn = self.request
        print 'connected...'
        while True:
            #####receive pre_data: we should get data like 'put|/home/aaa|7'
            pre_data = conn.recv(1024)
            print 'pre_data:' + pre_data
            cmd,file_name,file_size = pre_data.split('|')
            print 'cmd: ' + cmd
            print 'file_name: '+ file_name
            print 'file_size: '+ file_size
            recv_size = 0
            file_dir = os.path.join(base_path,file_name)
            f = file(file_dir,'wb')
            Flag = True
            ####receive 1024bytes each time
            while Flag:
                if int(file_size)>recv_size:
                    data = conn.recv(1024)
                    recv_size+=len(data)
                else:
                    recv_size = 0
                    Flag = False
                    continue

                f.write(data)
            print 'upload successed.'
            f.close()

instance = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer(('127.0.0.1',9999),MyServer)
instance.serve_forever()
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding:utf-8


################
#This is client#
################

import socket
import sys
import os

ip_port = ('127.0.0.1',9999)
sk = socket.socket()
sk.connect(ip_port)

while True:
    input = raw_input('path:')
    #####we should input like  'put|/home/aaa.txt'
    cmd,path = input.split('|')
    file_name = os.path.basename(path)
    file_size=os.stat(path).st_size
    sk.send(cmd+"|"+file_name+'|'+str(file_size))
    send_size = 0
    f= file(path,'rb')
    Flag = True
    #####read 1024 bytes and send it to server each time
    while Flag:
        if send_size + 1024 >file_size:
            data = f.read(file_size-send_size)
            Flag = False
        else:
            data = f.read(1024)
            send_size+=1024
        sk.send(data)
    f.close()

sk.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TCP is a stream of data. That is the problem. TCP do not need to keep message boundaries. So when a client calls something like

```
connection.send("0123456789")
connection.send("ABCDEFGHIJ")
```

then a naive server like

```
while True;
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print data + "_"
```

may print any of:

```
 0123456789_ABCDEFGHIJ_
 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJ_
 0_1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_A_B_C_D_E_F_G_H_I_J_
```

The server has no chance to recognize how many sends client called because the TCP stack at client side just inserted data to a stream and the server must be able to process the data received in different number of buffers than the client used.

Your server must contain a logic to separate the header and the data. All of application protocols based on TCP use a mechanism to identify application level boundaries. For example HTTP separates headers and body by an empty line and it informs about the body length in a separate header.

Your program works correctly when server receives a header with the command, name and size in a separate buffer it it fails when client is fast enough and push the data into stream quickly and the server reads header and data in one chunk.